# Its Tls 1.2 Padding required when message ist multiple of block length?

Tags: tls, padding

When I want to encrypt a 16 byte long message with AES-128-CBC using int TLS 1.2 do I need to add a 16 byte block of padding or can I just encrypt the message without padding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I want to encrypt a 16 byte long message with AES-128-CBC using int TLS 1.2 do I need to add a 16 byte block of padding or can I just encrypt the message without padding ?

You always need to add padding.  If you didn't, then the decryptor would be unable to distinguish between "this message was padded" and "this message wasn't padded, but happened to have data at the end that looks like padding".

So, if the data happens to be a multiple of 16 bytes long, you add a full 16 bytes of padding.

Also, in TLS 1.2 and CBC mode, you usually add the HMAC to the plaintext before encryption (hence in addition to your 16 bytes of data, there will be some additional bytes from the HMAC that will also be encrypted).  There is a negotiated extension to add the HMAC after the ciphertext instead ("Encrypt-then-MAC"); I don't believe it is in common use.